# Editor for Windows Explorer's context menu

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer, context-menu, shell-extensions

Does anyone know of a good application for editing the context menu's used by Windows explorer in Vista?

Reasons for wanting one:

- When I right click on a file, I get a very long list of things I can do with a file but never ever use.
- I'd like to add a custom entry for tools which don't register any shell extensions.

Comment: You don't need a shell extension to add entries there ...

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

[image]

Comment: Don't forget its partner program [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html)

Answer (score 2):

[FileMenu Tools](https://www.lopesoft.com/index.php/en/download/filemenu-tools) will do it. It's freeware.

Comment: Link is dead...Fixed

Comment: Fixed it again.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, here are other software that can also edit the Context Menu:

- [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/) - Its UI makes it easy to disable context menu of a specific file type.
- [MenuMaid](http://www.sdsoftware.org/software/menumaid/) - Its UI makes it easy to disable all context menu from a specific program.

Answer (score 0):

after trying most editors and regedit search ,i find a way to remove all unwanted entries(Adobe Bridge, Web Matrix, Git, Practicount, Winmerge, teraCopy) with ContextEdit tool.

500KB for v1.2

Open it as Administrator and search for "**File Folder**" and "**Folder**" Entry like below screenshot and look the right hand side 2 boxes and uncheck unwanted entries.

your changes will be reflected immediately
[image]

http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/ContextEdit.shtml